# Server 2012 domain controller vm and physical hosts

Tags: windows-server-2012, virtual-machines

I want to try out Server 2012 that is a domain controller running as VM on virtualbox or Hyper V running inside Windows 7. Can I still connect physical hosts to the domain controller AS well as vm hosts? Also is it possible to get trial vms as I don't want to purchase licences?

Comment: `running as VM on virtualbox or Hyper V running inside Windows 7`... What? You want to run a VM inside VM?

Comment: GregL No - the Windows 7 is a physical machine. It will either have virtual box OR hyper v running. Lets say virtual box. I want a server 2012 as a vm running in virtual box in this scenario.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I gotcha now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run a mix of virtual or physical Windows Server 2012 machines.  As far as domain functionality, being physical or virtual really has no bearing.

As for evals, see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2012.  It looks like as of this time you can get a 180 eval of Windows Server 2012